# how can i get value of input using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have file html with some input fields. i want to get value of all input when button click with jquery ?
thank for your help

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>No </td>
            <td>SKU </td>
            <td>Price</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1 </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[0][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder=""> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[0][price]" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[1][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder=""> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[1][price]" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3 </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[2][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder=""> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product[2][price]" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <button name="btn" id="btn">Get Product  </button>
      </body
</html>
```

Comment: This is a commonly written bit of functionality - what's giving you difficulty with it?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  const contents = $("#tb [name*=sku]").map(function() {
    return ({
      [$(this).val()]: $(this).closest("tr").find("[name*=price]").val()
    })
  }).get()
  console.log(contents)
})

// OR

$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  const contents = $("form").serializeArray();
  console.log(contents)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tb">
      <tr>
        <td>No </td>
        <td>SKU </td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[0][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku1"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[0][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="1.00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[1][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku2"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[1][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="2.00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[2][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku3"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[2][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="3.00"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<button name="btn" id="btn">Get Product  </button>
```

vanilla JS

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const contents = [...document.querySelectorAll("#tb [name*=sku]")].map(sku => 
   ({[sku.value] : sku.closest("tr").querySelector("[name*=price]").value})
   )
  console.log(contents)
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
  <tr>
    <td>No </td>
    <td>SKU </td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[0][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku1"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[0][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="1.00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[1][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku2"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[1][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="2.00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[2][sku]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="sku3"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product[2][price]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="3.00"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button name="btn" id="btn">Get Product  </button>
```

Comment: See update.....